# MongoDB Connecting to Atlas Cloud Database C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm having some trouble getting my C# app connected to my MongoDB on Atlas. The documentation on the website wants me to do this:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
// Replace the uri string with your MongoDB deployment's connection string.
var client = new MongoClient(
    "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster-address>/test?w=majority"
);
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
```

But the drivers I downloaded (version 2.13) dont seem to have the `GetDatabase` function in the `MongoClient` namespace. Doing some digging I found  a code snippet that seems to indicate that `GetDatabase` was depreciated in lieu of just using `MongoClient`. I just wanted to know if that was correct or if I had some bad drivers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're wrong. GetDatabase is not depricated: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient_GetDatabase.htm

Comment: MongoClient is not namespace, it's class